# how to use subprocess to automate shotcut commands in python?

Tags: python, automation

My python isn't that good yet so I hope you understand, I want to open the filters command in a program called shotcut then execute the rotate and scale and size and position commands, my question is how do you do that in python?

So far I poured over the web and only found how to execute program which is the following:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("C:\Program Files\Shotcut\Shotcut.exe")

proxy = subprocess.Popen("C:\Program Files\Shotcut\Shotcut.exe")

proxy.poll() == None

proxy.wait()
```

[image: how to execute filter?]

[image: then execute the two commands pointed out here]

Comment: Although you asked how to do that in Python i would suggest you to have a look at AutoIT. On windows it has a lot tools and predefined functions for automating the ui. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I will take a look, I would prefer how to do it in python though as I'm learning the language and automating repetitive tasks seem fun

Comment: I never did such thing in Python but this seems to be a good starting point (maybe you've seen it already): https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto